# Display:table-cell - change Height?

Tags: html, css

I have  this simple structure :

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div>
            <pre>aaa
                aaa
                aaa 
                aaa
            </pre>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div>
            <pre>1
                1
                1
                1
                1
                1
                1
                1
                1
                v
                1
                1
                1
                1
                1
                1
                1
                v
                1
                1
            </pre>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `wrapper` class has `display: table` and the 2 `.row` divs has `display: table-row;`

Inside those Divs there is a `div` which has `display: table-cell;`

[image]

I tried to set the `height` to  the **dashed div** , but did not succeed.

Question : how can I set a height to the dashed div ?

**NB**

- The wrapper/table doesn't have a fixed height.
- I want to use `display:table/table-row/table-cell` layout. ( no js or poistion absolute etc)

[**Full Jsbin**](http://jsfiddle.net/VzBE9/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following setting:

```
.row:last-child  > div {
    display: block;
}
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/VzBE9/2/)

Comment: You have this overriding setting: `.row > div { display: table-cell; }`

Comment: Is it inherited to childs ?

Comment: It's not a child it's the same level. Why do you need it anyway?

Comment: Why does in a pure Table I can set Td height while in my table-cell I can't ?

Comment: You're supposed to define the height of the `table-row`, not `table-cell`. See this: http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/VzBE9/3/

Comment: I was talking about height not width .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37413/discussion-between-royi-namir-and-itay)